# undefined method `model_name' for ActiveModel::Errors:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, activemodel

I have the following mongoid model class:

```
class Exercise
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String

  belongs_to :group

  validates_presence_of :name, :description, :group
end
```

And I have the following controller:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @exercise = Exercise.create(params[:exercise])
    if @exercise.save
      respond_with @exercise
    else
      respond_with(@exercise.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
end
```

The model saves fine when valid but when the following line is ran:

```
respond_with(@exercise.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity)
```

I get the following error

> undefined method `model_name' for ActiveModel::Errors:Class

The errors collection is populated so I think my respond_with syntax is wrong.

Comment: shouldn't you `respond_with(@exercise, ....)` instead of `respond_with(@exercise.errors, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

The rails respond_with helper expects to receive a rails model objects as the 1st parameter.  So in this case you'd just want respond_with @exercise, status: :unprocessable_entity  And then in your response view you would need to properly format the error data, I'm assuming you are doing this via ajax and responding with json, etc.  Hope that helps.